# How do I execute a command every time after ssh'ing from one machine to another?

Tags: ssh

How do I execute a command every time after ssh'ing from one machine to another?

e.g

```
ssh mymachine
stty erase ^H
```

I'd rather just have "stty erase ^H" execute every time after my ssh connection completes.

This command can't simply go into my .zshrc file.  i.e. for local sessions, I can't run the command (it screws up my keybindings).  But I need it run for my remote sessions.

Answer (score 12):

Put the commands in `~/.ssh/rc`

Answer (score 7):

You can put something like this into your shell's startup file:

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]
then
  stty erase ^H
end
```

The `-n` test will determine if `SSH_CONNECTION` is set which happens only when logged in via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

If you're logging into a *nix box with a shell, why not put it in your shell startup?

`.bashrc` or `.profile` in most cases.

Comment: Fair enough - I'd go with @geocar's suggestion then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a linux target, put it in your `.profile`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the command below the end of your ~/.bashrc. It should be exited upon logoff. Do you want this command *only* executed when logging off a ssh session? What about local sessions, etc?

```
trap 'stty erase ^H; exit 0' 0
```

You probably could setup a .logout file from /etc/profile using this same pattern as well.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for us, screen/byobu users:

The geocar's solution will not work as screen will complain that "Must be connected to a terminal.". (This is probably caused by the fact that .ssh/rc is processed *before* shell is started. See [LOGIN PROCESS](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/sshd/) section from `man 8 sshd`).

Robert's solution is better here but since screen and byobu open it's own bash instance, we need to avoid infinite recursion.  So here is adjusted byobu-friendly version:

```bsh
## RUN BYOBU IF SSH'D ##
## '''''''''''''''''' ##
# (but only if this is a login shell)

if shopt -q login_shell
then
    if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]
    then
        byobu
        exit
    fi
fi
```

Note that I also added `exit` after `byobu`, since IMO if you use byobu in the first place, you normally don't want to do anything outside of it.